# Synonym proposal: [docker-network] -> [docker-networking]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

There are two nearly identical tags for network questions related to Docker.

While most of the questions in both tags seem off-topic (not about programming), it seems that having two separate and (at least to me) indistinguishable tags is clearly excessive.

Personally, I would prefer [docker-network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker-network) as the primary tag; but [docker-networking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker-networking) has more questions (966 vs 265), more watchers (134 vs 28), and a tag wiki.

On the other hand, `docker network` is a specific Docker subcommand, similar to `docker build`, `docker run`, etc; perhaps there is some merit in theory to attempting to keep the two separate? But in practice, I don't think we can.

There are a few dozen users with enough reputation in either tag to propose and vote on a synonym proposal; my impression is that this is by far insufficient to successfully establish a synonym without moderator involvement (though pointers to guidelines or statistics to better inform this are most welcome).

Comment: Not enough rep on the tag to vote but I'd prefer docker-network as a primary tag as well and I don't think we need two. The tag wiki can probably be moved over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the nomenclature of the other tags, I think [docker-network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker-network) is the better option as well. Tags merged and synonym created.